# Xcode: pod install error when creating new projects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, cocoapods

firstly I am really new to iOS dev and to MAC's (Only owned one for a week)

I am trying to create an iOS application which requires a pod install, I have installed cocopods etc and I navigate to my project directory. I have then generated the pod file and added my required dependencies. When it run pod install, I get an error,

```text
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Top of error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
/Users/pilotman/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:36: [BUG] Illegal instruction at 0x00000001021b4000
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
```

Bottom of error:

```
[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

zsh: abort      pod install
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This Question is pretty general...
Are you using an Macbook M1? Or an Intel Macbook?

If you are using an Intel macbook ...

- $sudo gem install cocoapods
- move to your folder run pod init
- open your Podfile and add your targets e.g.

  ```
  #platform :ios, '9.0'
  target 'MyPod' do
  # Pods for MyPod
       pod 'Firebase/Auth' 

  end
  ```
- Close Podfile
- type pod install
- type pod update
- Open MyPod.xcworkspace and start working

if you are using M1 Mb do the same but start with

1. Right click on Terminal
2. Get Info -> Open with Rosetta
3. Open terminal and type sudo gem install ffi

Then do the steps above.

If this error is still occur let me know.

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem. I reproduced those steps but I get still this error. In my `Podfile` there are the following pods: `Firebase/Analytics`, `Firebase/Auth` and `Firebase/Firestore`.

Answer (score 13):

If you are on a Apple silicon then just do this

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: Perfect resolved for my m1 macbook. Also had error after running pod install "xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located" which I resolved with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565356/xcrun-error-sdk-iphoneos-cannot-be-located

Comment: ahh that is nice, awesome that you added the link to that since a lot of users will also have that error. Awesome @Dylanw

Comment: this does not work when you need cocoapods-generate

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following commands:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```